# Identifying rearrangement reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was asked to solve this problem, and the answer key shows this:

[image: molecule]

I'm not sure what's going on here, but it looks like some sort of a rearrangement and reduction. Is it an internal reaction between the ether and the alkene?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of the [Claisen rearrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claisen_rearrangement).  It is basically the oxa-analogue of the [Cope rearrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cope_rearrangement).  The Claisen rearrangement can occur with aromatic or non-aromatic allyl vinyl ethers.  The reaction mechanism involves a concerted, intramolecular, [3,3]-sigmatropic rearrangement.  In the aromatic case, the rearrangement is followed by a proton shift (keto-enol tautomerization) to yield the final product with the aromaticity restored.

Here's a diagram of the aromatic Claisen rearrangement

[image]

Here's a diagram for the non-aromatic counterpart.

[image]

Comment: From the historical perspective, the Cope rearrangement is a carbon analog of the Claisen rearrangement. ;)